# Modelling the PID controller for a Buck Converter from a given schematic

Tags: power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, buck, control-system, pid-controller

I followed a document to implement a PID controller for a Si MOSFET based buck converter as the traditional multistep analog PID converter was not giving any good results for some reason. The document that I followed did give the formulas to calculate the resistor and the capacitor values used in that converter however I am facing some issues while modelling the converter and finding the transfer function.
The following are the schematic for the whole circuit and the hand-drawn schematic for the converter (where Vin is the output voltage of the converter).
[image: Altium Simulation schematic]
[image: Hand drawn schematic for the converter]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147254/discussion-on-question-by-lakshman-modelling-the-pid-controller-for-a-buck-conve); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

The op-amp-based filter you have described is not a PID but a filtered-PID with an additional pole in high frequency. A classical PID brings a pole at the origin for a high dc gain and two zeroes. That is all. For stability and noise reasons, you then add a pole, to force the gain roll-off at high frequencies: it becomes a *filtered PID*. See this picture excerpted from my [APEC 2012](http://powersimtof.com/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202012.pdf) seminar:

[image]

Compensators for switching converters have been classified in three types after a paper published by [Dean Venable](https://www.venableinstruments.com/hubfs/The%20K%20Factor%20a%20New%20Mathematical%20Tool%20for%20Stability%20Analysis.pdf) in 1990:

- type 1: a simple integrator, provides gain at dc and lets you adjust crossover without phase boost
- type 2: an integrator with a pole-zero pair whose distance between the two adjusts the phase boost between 0 and 90°
- type 3: an integrator with a double pole-zero pair whose distance between the two pairs lets you tweak the phase boost from 0 to 180° theoretically.

You have drawn a type 3 and you see that you are missing two poles to match your PID coefficients. The transfer function of a type 3 is here:

[image]

If you now want to find the match between the type 3 and a *modified* PID, there is a bit of maths:

[image]

If you are into loop control and modeling, you'll find plenty of documents to freely download from my [page](http://powersimtof.com/Spice.htm).

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Why is the 2nd added pole not being considered when the PID is being converted to Type-3 and vice versa? When we implement the type-3 using the op amps there is an added pole but when we are comparing the transfer functions to convert one type to another we are only considering 2 poles for the type-3. Why is that so?

Comment: A PID, alone, only features 1 pole at the origin, 2 zeroes and some adjustable gain. Because of noise reasons, one often adds another pole, beyond the zeroes, to force the gain flattening out to a 0-slope: it is the *filtered* PID you often see implemented. In switching power supplies, because of the inherent noise, it is important to further force high-frequency gain roll off by a adding a 2nd pole to obtain good gain margin hence the type 3. The comparison I did with equations bridging the two compensators is there to show the type 3 was a filtered PID to which an additional pole is added.

Comment: so that additional pole does not affect the kp, ki and kd gains if we try to find those coefficients for a Type 3 implementation?

Comment: Correct, it is not in the PID.

Comment: but what affect does it have then on the performance if the Gains (PID equivalent) are not affected by that pole

Comment: you say that the 2nd pole is added to increase the gain margin (hence stablise the system). Shouldn't it affect the gain coefficients of the equivalent PID system? or are you saying that the effect is minimal?

Comment: I said that if you want to build a type 3 with an existing filtered PID, you have to add an extra pole externally.

Comment: yes I understand that but what I don't understand is that making a type 3 from a PID by adding an extra pole does change the gain margin and stabilizes the system. Can we possibly find the Kp, Ki and Kd coefficients from the Type 3 filter directly to inorder to directly control the overshoot, steady state error and other parameters of the system's performance?